# WxPython. How to close the cell editor?

Tags: python, wxpython

How to implement closing your own cell editor when it loses focus? Since the built-in wx editors work.

Now my editor closes only if you select another cell in the grid. And, for example, the cell editor (0, 1) closes if you click on the button, and not just when you click on another cell.

My editor and renderer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import wx.grid


class GridCellColourEditor(wx.grid.GridCellEditor):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def Create(self, parent, id, evtHandler):
        self._cp = wx.ColourPickerCtrl(parent, id)
        self.SetControl(self._cp)

        if evtHandler:
            self._cp.PushEventHandler(evtHandler)

    def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        self.startValue = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)
        self._cp.SetColour(self.startValue)
        self._cp.SetFocus()

    def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid, oldval):
        val = self._cp.GetColour().GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX)
        if val != oldval:
            return val
        else:
            return None

    def ApplyEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        val = self._cp.GetColour().GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX)
        grid.GetTable().SetValue(row, col, val)

    def Reset(self):
        self._cp.SetColour(self.startValue)

    def Clone(self):
        return GridCellColourEditor()

class GridCellColourRenderer(wx.grid.GridCellRenderer):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def Draw(self, grid, attr, dc, rect, row, col, isSelected):
        if grid.IsEnabled():
            bgColour = grid.GetDefaultCellBackgroundColour()
        else:
            bgColour = grid.GetBackgroundColour()

        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(bgColour, wx.SOLID))
        dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
        dc.DrawRectangle(rect)

        colour = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)

        x = rect.x + 3
        y = rect.y + 3
        width = rect.width - 6
        height = rect.height - 6

        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(colour, wx.SOLID))
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK))
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(x, y, width, height, 3)

    def GetBestSize(self, grid, attr, dc, row, col):
        return attr.GetSize()

    def Clone(self):
        return GridCellColourRenderer()

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self, size=(100, 50))
        vbox.Add(self.grid, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(1, 2)

        self.grid.SetCellEditor(0, 0, GridCellColourEditor())
        self.grid.SetCellRenderer(0, 0, GridCellColourRenderer())

        self.grid.SetCellEditor(0, 1, wx.grid.GridCellTextEditor())
        self.grid.SetCellRenderer(0, 1, wx.grid.GridCellStringRenderer())

        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'For kill focus')
        vbox.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(vbox)

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Why, if wx.TextCtrl is used as wx.Control, then the cell editor successfully closes when focus is lost. And if you use wx.ColourPickerCtrl, the editor does not close?

Answer (score 0):

It solved my problem

```
class GridCellColourEditor(wx.grid.GridCellEditor):

    def Create(self, parent, id, evtHandler):
        self._parent = parent
        self._colourDialog = None
        self._colourButton = wx.Button(parent, id, "")
        self.SetControl(self._colourButton)
        newEventHandler = wx.EvtHandler()
        if evtHandler:
            self._colourButton.PushEventHandler(newEventHandler)
        self._colourButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        self._colourButton.SetFocus()
        self.ShowColourDialog()

    def SetSize(self, rect):
        self._colourButton.SetSize(rect.x, rect.y,
                                   rect.width + 2, rect.height + 2,
                                   wx.SIZE_ALLOW_MINUS_ONE)

    def Clone(self):
        return GridCellColourEditor()

    def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        self._grid = grid
        self._row = row
        self._col = col
        self._parent.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnParentLeftDown)
        self._parent.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnParentKillFocus)

        self.startValue = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)
        self.endValue = self.startValue
        self._colourButton.SetBackgroundColour(self.startValue)

    def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid, oldval):
        self._parent.Unbind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN)
        self._parent.Unbind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS)

        if self.endValue != self.startValue:
            return self.endValue
        else:
            return None

    def ApplyEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        val = self.endValue.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX)
        grid.GetTable().SetValue(row, col, val)

    def Reset(self):
        self._colourButton.SetBackgroundColour(self.startValue)

    def ShowColourDialog(self):
        colourDialog = wx.ColourDialog(self._parent)
        self._colourDialog = colourDialog
        colourDialog.GetColourData().SetColour(self.startValue)
        if colourDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            data = colourDialog.GetColourData()
            colour = data.GetColour()
            self._colourButton.SetBackgroundColour(colour)
            self.endValue = colour

        self._parent.SetFocus()

        del self._colourDialog
        self._colourDialog = None

    def OnParentLeftDown(self, event: wx.MouseEvent):
        def CheckCellChange():
            row = self._grid.GetGridCursorRow()
            col = self._grid.GetGridCursorCol()
            if self._row == row and self._col == col:
                # клик в области сетки, но ячейка не изменилась
                self._grid.CloseEditControl()
        wx.CallAfter(CheckCellChange)
        event.Skip()

    def OnParentKillFocus(self, event: wx.FocusEvent):
        if self._parent.FindFocus() != self._colourButton:
            self._grid.CloseEditControl()
        event.Skip()
```